# Teensy's #include <TimeLib.h> got overridden by Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, time.h, time-t, teensy

In Arduino C+, I wanted to avoid the year 2038 overflow problem when using 32-bit, signed **time_t** type, so that I'd like to specifically use the **Time.h** from Teensy (Or TimeLib.h for that matter; I am writing code for Teensy 3.5 on Arduino 1.8.7).

But the IDE seems to ignore Teensy's Time.h, in which time_t is defined as:

```
typedef unsigned long time_t;
```

I find out that no matter what I include, the time_t type I am using is compiled as "long int". This code reveals that:

```
time_t t = "ABC";
```

The compiler will show that **time_**t is actually defined somewhere as **long int**:

```
invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'time_t {aka long int}' [-fpermissive]
```

I even tried copying the Teensy's Time folder (https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time) to my sketch folder, and do this to no avail:

```
#include "Time\TimeLib.h"
```

How to make sure that I am using an unsigned, 32-bit time_t in Arduino?
Also I want when I call **now()** it's Teensy's **now()** that returns unsigned long **time_t**, not the built-in long int **time_t**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In teensy TimeLib.h it's defined as:

```
#if !defined(__time_t_defined) // avoid conflict with newlib or other posix libc
typedef unsigned long time_t;
#endif
```

and the `sys/_types.h` defines it as:

```
#define _TIME_T_    long        /* time() */
typedef _TIME_T_    __time_t;
```

Used in several places as:

```
#if !defined(__time_t_defined) && !defined(_TIME_T_DECLARED)
typedef _TIME_T_    time_t;
#define __time_t_defined
#define _TIME_T_DECLARED
#endif
```

So it's not such a mystery it's ignored. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to compile because of conflicting types.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see more clearly. Is there a way to override the definition in sys/_types.h?

Comment: @Dave depends on usage. If you want to use TimeLib, it might be better to change time_t to utime_t or something similar everywhere. Or maybe hide it into separate namespace